# How to run a function in Django after a certain time passed by

Tags: django, asynchronous

Having the model of `Station` with the below fields:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    unavailable_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I can define until when my station is unavailable by giving a `DateTime` value , so when that action happens the `is_available` value turns to `False`.

I want to turn the `is_available` value to `True` every time the `unavailable_until` value passed by(comparing with the current time based on the timezone).

**How can I achieve an automation like this?**

Imagine that I have a lot of `Station` records which belong to station owners which can update the availability (assign new `unavailable_until` value if passed by) whenever they want.

I think the logic could be something like:

```
def turn_availability_to_true(station):
   if (station.unavailable_until < current_time):
       station.is_available = True
```

**But how can I implement a function like this to be called by its own when the `unavailable_until` value passed by?**

Comment: You can omit storing `is_available` and use a property or annotation. That way it is simply impossible that the `uniavailable_until` has passed, and `is_available` is still `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a field, you can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to calculate dynamically if the `Station` is available:

The model thus then looks like

```
class Station(models.Model):
    # no is_available
    unavailable_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

and we annotate this with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Station.objects.annotate(
    is_available=ExpressionWrapper(
        ~Q(unavailable_until__gte=Now()),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

If you need this often, you can implement a [*manager* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/) that will automatically add this to the `Station`s:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class StationManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            is_available=ExpressionWrapper(
                ~Q(unavailable_until__gte=Now()),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )

class Station(models.Model):
    # no is_available
    unavailable_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    objects = StationManager()
```

The advantage of not running a scheduled task is that it is hard to alter that task if later the `unavailable_until` field is modified, for example to a later date. In that case, one has to *remove* the scheduled task, and schedule a new one. By annotating, we avoid synchronization issues.

Comment: @gtopal: but you *can* use it on several locations inside your project. The objects that arise from the annotated queryset have a `.is_available` attribute, you can also `.filter(is_available=True)` if the queryset is annotated. So if you implement the manager, you can keep most of the logic.